# Change Data of Range().Value Reference after Copy and Paste Hardcoded Data from Table

Tags: excel, vba

I wish to create a VBA command that will reference range values using variables and then copy and paste to those files mentioned in the ranges. The command will pull from a table and put it in the reference range for the copy and paste command. I am having issues getting it to work past the first reference. I tried adding save commands and wait time commands to see if that would do anything, but no progress has been made.

Images:

[Data Reference for Copy and Paste](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGYo0.png)

[Table that Will Replace Data on First Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHhP6.png)

[Debugging Showing that Reference Data Won't Change Even if Data in Range Does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah8ni.png)

This is what I have so far:

```
Public Sub Changing_Variable_Loop()
'--Variables
CopyFile = Range("A1").Value
CopyWksht = Range("B1").Value
CopyRange = Range("C1").Value

PasteFile = Range("D1").Value
PasteWksht = Range("E1").Value
PasteRange = Range("F1").Value

'--Change Range("").Value Reference Data in Excel Sheet (1)
Workbooks("VBA Command.xlsm").Activate
Range("A1").Select

Workbooks("VBA Command.xlsm").Worksheets("Pull").Range("A1:F1").Copy _
Workbooks("VBA Command.xlsm").Worksheets("Post").Range("A1:F1")

Workbooks("VBA Command.xlsm").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Save

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

'--Copy and Paste for Varying Files based on Range("").Value Reference Data(1)

Workbooks(CopyFile).Worksheets(CopyWksht).Range(CopyRange).Copy _
Workbooks(PasteFile).Worksheets(PasteWksht).Range(PasteRange)


'--Change Range("").Value Reference Data in Excel Sheet (2)
Workbooks("VBA Command.xlsm").Worksheets("Pull").Range("A2:F2").Copy _
Workbooks("VBA Command.xlsm").Worksheets("Post").Range("A1:F1")

Workbooks("VBA Command.xlsm").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Save

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

'--Copy and Paste for Varying Files based on Range("").Value Reference Data(2)

Workbooks(CopyFile).Worksheets(CopyWksht).Range(CopyRange).Copy _
Workbooks(PasteFile).Worksheets(PasteWksht).Range(PasteRange)


'--Change Range("").Value Reference Data in Excel Sheet (3)
Workbooks("VBA Command.xlsm").Worksheets("Pull").Range("A3:F3").Copy _
Workbooks("VBA Command.xlsm").Worksheets("Post").Range("A1:F1")

Workbooks("VBA Command.xlsm").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Save

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

'--Copy and Paste for Varying Files based on Range("").Value Reference Data(3)

Workbooks(CopyFile).Worksheets(CopyWksht).Range(CopyRange).Copy _
Workbooks(PasteFile).Worksheets(PasteWksht).Range(PasteRange)

MsgBox ("Successful")
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have any recommendations for code simplification or loops I will greatly appreciate your advice. Thank you.

Comment: `debug.print` your variables to confirm they are what you want them to be.

Comment: @findwindow you are correct, it seems the variable stays the same, even though the data is changing in the excel sheet. Is there any way to correct that so that it references the new data that is replacing "A1:F1" on the Post sheet from "A1:F1" & "A2:F2" & "A3:F3" from the Pull sheet?

Comment: Unclear what you're doing.

Comment: Your code would be much easier to follow if you use some worksheet variables an (eg) `ThisWorkbook` instead of `Workbooks("VBA Command.xlsm")` (assuming that's where this code is running)

Comment: The goal is to copy one workbook to paste to another workbook. I have a ton of clients that change, so it would be annoying to go into VBA and hardcode the name of the new workbooks. Instead I made a table of all the workbooks, so that the code can reuse the same range variable, yet get different workbook data since the excel sheet data gets replaced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code could be a lot simpler - more like this:

```vb
Public Sub RunCopyPasteSettings()
    
    Dim wsSettings As Worksheet, i As Long, rw As Range
    
    Set wsSettings = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings") 'or whatever
    
    Set rw = wsSettings.Range("A1:F1") 'your first row of copy/paste settings
    
    For i = 1 To 3 'or however many rows of settings you have
        
        Workbooks(rw.Cells(1).Value).Worksheets(rw.Cells(2).Value). _
            Range(rw.Cells(3).Value).Copy _
            Workbooks(rw.Cells(4).Value).Worksheets(rw.Cells(5).Value). _
            Range(rw.Cells(6).Value)
    
        Set rw = rw.Offset(1) 'next row of copy/paste range settings
        
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for your code as it has been helpful the past week. If I wanted to paste values how would I adjust your code to do that? I tried adding .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues to the end of the For Loop but it creates a syntax error.